# Store Access and Refresh Token for Command

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, command-line-interface, refresh-token

I plan to develop a command line client for a web API protected by OAuth 2 (JWT). The access and refresh tokens live for five and thirty minutes, respectively. Since the user will use the command line client for longer than five minutes in a sitting (a testing or debugging session, for example), the refresh token needs to be stored on the local computer, so that only one authentication is needed at the beginning of the session, and not later on.

I wonder where I can store the refresh token securely. A text file in the user's home directory might not sound too bad, because that's also the place the user stores all his or her private documents. However, any other application run by the same user could read that token and misuse it.

What are common solutions to such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use **[Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)** in which you will use command prompt to get end user credentials and exchange them for tokens. With that, you can think of a way to encrypt received tokens based on end user credentials you got when requesting tokens. So whenever you require to use refresh token, you can prompt end user for their password so that you do not store the password but also you encrypt tokens so no other process can steal them as it is.

Comment: Prompting for the password exactly defeats the point of storing the refresh token locally.

Comment: @PatrickBucher well the thing here is focus on security. You can build the API and secure it by access tokens. You can protect the token obtaining by using the best Identity Server available. But if you cannot store your tokens in clients which consume API, then you simply open up vulnerabilities. If you want to store something securely in a file system, then you need to think about encrypting mechanism. I wrote my suggestion from this perspective.

Comment: One more thing, how do you obtain tokens to command line application ? Is it a copy paste approach or do you use a grant type as I highlighted.

Comment: The user is prompted for the password, unless the password is already provided by a parameter. This can happen safely when using a command-line password manager such as `pass`: `my-cli-app login -u johndoe -p $(pass show whatever)`.

Comment: If I'd ask the user every time for his password, there would not be a need to _store_ the access token in any way, I just could obtain another one.

Comment: @PatrickBucher well see the point. You provide the password and then store it inside a password manager which is encrypted. why ? To secure the original password. What you need to understand is the importance of protecting tokens. You must store them securely. What I suggest you is the same, protecting tokens as password.

Comment: Yes, obtaining fresh token everytime is more or less similar to encrypting and then using a refresh token. It all boils down to security, so do not store tokens as it is. That's my 2 cents.

Comment: Yes, not in plain text, at least. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use ROPG as Kavindu says - if you have an implementation that supports refresh tokens

After that you can store tokens in memory or via OS secure storage. The choice is a little subjective and depends on sensitivity of data being accessed

If using OS secure storage then store tokens per app + user, to ensure isolation

An example cross platform component that does this is keytar, which I've used in the past for desktop apps - it is nodejs based -not sure if this works for you:
https://github.com/atom/node-keytar/blob/master/README.md

[Sample code that uses it](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/tokenStorage.ts)

See the OS Secure Storage section of this write up to understand how the entry can be viewed + managed via built in OS tools:
https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/

Comment: I will use ROP(C)G; the issue is more how to store the tokens than how to get them (that's already given from the API I'm going to use.) So OS key stores are the way to go...